# When to use "one" over "somebody" or "someone"?

Tags: word-usage

> *This question is particularly apropos when you’re faced with a naive or
> straightforward solution to a computational problem. In the third
> grade, you might not have asked if **one** could do better than the
> straightforward integer multiplication algorithm. Now is the time to
> ask, and answer, this question.*

Could you guys explain to me why the author from text above used *one* over *somebody* or *someone*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Before I get to the answer, it's worth noting that in North American English, using "one" like this sounds archaic, like from the 1800s or older, so I don't recommend using it yourself, unless that's the effect you're looking for.)

Generally speaking, you use "one" in the place of the impersonal "you", not "someone". The difference is if the "one" stands in for *people in general*, not a specific, unnamed or unknown person.

For instance, you can say:

> One must keep one's wits if one is to survive.

In modern language, we would say, "You must keep your wits if you are to survive." This is general advice.

We usually cannot use "one" to replace "someone":

> I think someone's in my house. (correct)
> <del>I think one is in my house</del>. (incorrect)

Your example sentence, however, uses the idiomatic expression "*one could do better*". That expression sounds somewhat less archaic, but still old.

Comment: I don't think that 'one' used that way is howlingly archaic, just a little formal, or 'educated' perhaps. I see it in the Guardian all the time, and use it in speech frequently. The problem with the quoted text, I think, is that the writer used the informal 'you're' in the first sentence, and then veers over to the bookish 'one' in the second.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm guessing it's a pondial difference, so I've amended my first paragraph. One can't be too careful.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it's not used universally, and, as I say, tends to have an 'educated' and 'formal' reputation, and perhaps is seen as old-fashioned by younger folk.

Comment: The late queen was famously believed to only say 'one', and never 'I'. I don't think this was always true, if it ever was. A passer-by rescued Princess Anne from a kidnap attempt by an armed man in 1974, and got the George Medal for his bravery. He said that when the queen presented it to him at Buckingham Palace, she said 'I give you this medal as a queen, but I thank you as a mother'.

Answer (score -1):

"One" is not used very commonly these days.

The second sentence would often be phrased as

> (When you were) in the third grade you might not have asked if you could do better ...

or by using passive voice, as

> (When you were) in the third grade you might not have asked if it was possible to do better ...

In this context "do better than than the straightforward integer multiplication algorithm" refers to finding a better algorithm. Using "somebody" or "someone" instead of "one" would be asking if there is a *person* who could do better, instead of asking if there is a *way* to do better.

See [Pronouns: one, you, we, they](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-one-you-we-they) about the usage of "one".